# How to signal end of stream?

Tags: stream-processing, video, c++14

I am designing an interface for reading and writing video frames to various inputs and outputs. Stream operators seem to me a superb alternative to named functions for the task. This is the gist of it:

```
struct FrameSource
{
    virtual FrameSource & operator>>( cv::Mat & frame ) = 0;
    virtual ~FrameSource() = default;
};

struct FrameSink
{
    virtual FrameSink & operator<<( const cv::Mat & frame ) = 0;
    virtual ~FrameSink() = default;
};
```

Now, supposing this is an OK design, **how should I signal end of stream** (end of video; last picture in the folder; deinitialized camera)?

The options I have considered:

- `EndOfIteration` exception, like in python. Sounds slow, dangerous and not idiomatic. No way to indicate this behaviour in the header.
- Return `cv::Mat{}`. Sounds slow, easy to miss(leading to infinite loops), violates the invariant that any frame can be returned, not idiomatic.
- `cv::Mat f; while(stream.get(f));` [idiomatic](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) but involves named functions, return status easy to miss.
- A variation of the above via the conversion operator `operator bool() const;`.
- Derive from `std::basic_i/ostream`. But those are character based.
- Derive from `iterator` and provide `begin(), end()`.

My application doesn't mandate streams, I am using them because of the subjective advantages of:

- ease of use
- not having to hold a bunch of large files in working memory simultaneously.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between end-of-stream and error?

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes, I am using a simple `struct Exception : public runtime_error {};` for the latter.

Comment: You mention the advantage "not having to hold a bunch of large files in working memory simultaneously". This has absolutely nothing to do with using stream-operators vs using named functions: A stream-operator is still a function call, just like a named function, so both methods can achieve exactly the same things.

Comment: @pschill streams as opposed to an iterable vector.

Comment: @Vorac You can program something that behaves like a stream even if you use named functions instead of the stream operators. I think that helps the user to understand what happens and allows you to use additional arguments (e.g., a `bool& end_of_stream` argument which cannot be ignored like a return value). If you really want to stick to operator<< and operator>>, you should probably use them in a standard-fashion: Provide some `operator bool()` which allows the common `while (stream >> value)` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide a stream-like interface, I would strongly recommend to provide an interface that is comparable to that provided by `std::basic_i/ostream`. For error reporting (including EOF), this would involve the member functions `operator!` and `operator bool` (which in `std::basic_i/ostream` are based on the member functions `good`, `eof`, `fail`, `bad`).

Comment: Isn't the standard I/O streams interface known to be hard to use and overly complicated? The difference or relationship between `good`, `eof`, `fail` and `bad` are especially hard to grasp and memorise, and the names are really bad (IMO). For the sake of simplicity, it might be better if the OP just provided `operator bool`, because that seems to be enough for his use case.